# Database Connection String Info

Tags: c#

In .Net is there a class in .Net where you can get the DB name, and all the connection string info without acutally doing a substring on the connection string?

EDIT:

I am not creating a connection I am attempting to get info out of the connection string. So I am basicly looking for something that takes a connection string arg and has accessors to dbName, connection type, etc....

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the provider-specific ConnectionStringBuilder class (within the appropriate namespace), or `System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder` to abstract the connection string object if you need to. You'd need to know the provider-specific keywords used to designate the information you're looking for, but for a SQL Server example you could do either of these two things:

Given

```
string connectionString = "Data Source = .\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;";
```

You could do...

```
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder();

builder.ConnectionString = connectionString;

string server = builder["Data Source"] as string;
string database = builder["Database"] as string;
```

Or

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

builder.ConnectionString = connectionString;

string server = builder.DataSource;
string database = builder.InitialCatalog;
```

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);`

Answer (score 3):

After you initialize the connection with the connection string, you can get those information from properties of the initialized connection object.

Check System.Data.Common.DbConnection.

Comment: This requires that you create a connection object, which seems like overkill for this application.

Answer (score 0):

Yep ConnectionInfo

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms226340(VS.80).aspx

EDIT: I, along with Chris, realized that this is only works if you have the Crystal Reports namespaces imported. Otherwise I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

```
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo ();
connectionInfo = logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo;

connectionInfo.DatabaseName = database;
connectionInfo.ServerName = server;
connectionInfo.Password = password;
connectionInfo.UserID = user;
```

**EDIT**: Looks like Nathan beat me to it, as mine is from the same page.

**EDIT AGAIN**: I should note that ConnectionInfo is in the CrystalDecisions.Shared namespace. As for how to get it from a generic DB connection, I'm not sure.

Comment: isn't connectioninfo in the crystal reports library?

Answer (score 0):

if you build your connection string using the Connection string builder (e.g. OracleConnectionStringBuilde, and it  will be different for different database), in that case easily retrieve the information out of it.

here it explained:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947.aspx

Answer (score -3):

```
SqlConnection sq = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx)

Done with "using" statement (from MSDN)

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        // Do work here; connection closed on following line.
    }
```

Comment: he's looking to get information from the connectionstring without parsing. This allows him to use the connection, not determine what the database name is.

Comment: You're connecting to the database...there's no reason that he should have to do that.