# Single.NaN doesn't equal itself?

Tags: c#, nan

I came across this while debugging some unit tests that compared a returned single array against the expected results.

```
System.Single.NaN == System.Single.Nan;
```

The unit test was expecting true, but this evaluates to false. Why does this evaluate to false when the other static methods of single return true? Is NaN not a constant value ?

```
System.Single.MaxValue == System.Single.MaxValue;
System.Single.Epsilon == System.Single.Epsilon;
null == null;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.nan.aspx states: "Two NaN values are considered unequal to one another." but this question is out of curiosity as to why this is so more than anything else.

Comment: If you will consider what NaN actually means than it may be easier to understand why NaNs are never equal.
"A" is NaN, "b" is NaN too, "some other B****s" is still NaN. Are they equal? No.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the IEEE 754 standard (the one used for `float` and `double`) says so.

To quote the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)

> A comparison with a NaN always returns an unordered result even when comparing with itself. The comparison predicates are either signaling or non-signaling, the signaling versions signal an invalid exception for such comparisons. The equality and inequality predicates are non-signaling so x = x returning false can be used to test if x is a quiet NaN. The other standard comparison predicates are all signaling if they receive a NaN operand, the standard also provides non-signaling versions of these other predicates. The predicate isNaN(x) determines if a value is a NaN and never signals an exception, even if x is a signaling NaN.

(note that .NET doesn't support the signaling NaN, and probably treats it as non-signaling)

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. NaN == NaN is always false. This is a way to test if a certain variable is equal to NaN, like

> if(x != x)
>    //do something

Answer (score 0):

Someone once [asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706566/database-connection-string-info) about `Double.NaN`. The best answer I could find in that post was "because that's the way it's defined".

Not very satisfying, I agree.